# Does cordova support Indexeddb at last 12.4 iOS version?

Tags: ios, cordova, indexeddb

At the moment, I was confused by the choice of technology for the implementation of my project. I stopped looking at indexddb. However, on the official website of Cordoba, it is indicated that only Android and Windows are supported for this database.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html

IndexedDB is supported by the underlying WebView on the following Cordova platforms:
    Windows (with some limitations)
    Android (4.4 and above)

Can someone reliably say whether it works on the latest version of iOS, or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [MongOGX](https://github.com/globules-io/mongogx/wiki) if you wish to store your data as JSON in a mongodb-like database. In this case you would store the base64 of your image